# How to clone a button multiple times in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I'm cloning a div on button click it works perfectly.
but the problem is that i also want to duplicate a div according to url parameters value for example `(localhost/app/index-2.html?zipCode=78001&**empNo=15**)`

if empNo= 3 then clone 3 time , else if 4 then 4 times.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: And what is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: It's pretty basic. What have you tried?

Comment: please, provide a basic code to understand better your problem. In addition, you could create several DOM objects in a loop with jQuery and append them to any other object, just using a simple javascript for statement and doing something like this:
str = str + '<div id="elem_' + i + '"></div>'
$('#someId').append($(str));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find the parameter in the url so you know how many times you want to duplicate.

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
var num = parseInt(getQueryVariable('empNo'));
```

We call parseInt on the result since it's going to return a string.

Finally, we can use this number to do our duplication with a loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    //duplicate div
}
```

Put all of this inside your button click event handler and it should work! :)

Comment: @Viveksaroch mark this answer as correct if it worked, thanks :)

Comment: i have one more question please reply if you have any idea

Comment: i have one more question please help
i want to clone a div on the basis of select dropdown selection.
for example **1.)** if someone choose 3 then clone a div 3 time. 
**2.)** if choose **5** then clone **5 times**. 
**3.)** again if choose **2** then again the remaining total length of div is 2.
thanks in advance

Comment: It depends, I need to see what the select looks like. If it has an id attribute you can do: `var num = document.getElementById('select-id').value` and then use a similar loop.